# Ruby bit banging, how to perform additive and negative

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I have a 2 collections of bitmasks, 1 has permissions that I want to combine, and the other collection has bitmasks I want to remove.

For additive, I just 'OR' them like:

```
permissions = 0
add_masks.each do |x|
 permissions |= permissions
end
```

How do I remove permissions using the other collection?

```
remove_masks.each do |x|
    ???
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use `permissions &= ~mask`:

```
irb > permissions = 0
 # => 0 
irb > permissions |= 512
 # => 512 
irb > permissions |= 256
 # => 768 
irb > permissions &= ~1
 # => 768 
irb > permissions &= ~256
 # => 512 
irb > permissions &= ~512
 # => 0
```

Answer (score -1):

`~(~a|b)` is bitwise subtraction of b from a

Comment: uhh, what doesn't work? my answer is logically equivalent to (a&(~b))